# useEffect is being called twice even if it state is changed once

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

i made login hook called **"useMakeQueryString"**. which is responsble for making queryString from Object.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function  useMakeQueryString(obj) {
  const [queryString, setQueryString] = useState("");

  const makeQueryString=(obj)=> {
      let queryString1 = "";
      for (let key in obj) {
        //if (key instanceof Object) queryString1 += makeQueryString(obj);
        queryString1 += key + "=" + obj[key] + "&";
      }
         setQueryString(queryString1.slice(0, queryString1.length - 1));
  }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    makeQueryString(obj)
  },[obj])

  return { queryString, makeQueryString };
}
```

then i imported that hook to my Google Component. on click of Component it calls the ***performAuth*** function and that function set the ***option*** state. and useEffect on ***option*** change is called. inside useEffect which is being called on ***option*** change i try to change ***queryString*** State. but the problem is useEffect on ***queryString*** change is being Called Twice

```
import useMakeQueryString from "../Login/LoginHook";
import { useEffect,useState } from "react";

export default function Google() {
    const g_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
    const {queryString,makeQueryString} = useMakeQueryString({});
    let [option,setOption]  = useState({})

     useEffect(() => {
        console.log("length"+Object.keys(option).length)
          if(Object.keys(option).length!=0) {
             makeQueryString(option);       // setQueryString(query);
          }
       
    }, [option])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(queryString)
         window.location = `${g_url}?${queryString}`;
    },[queryString])
    
      const performAuth = () => {
         console.log("perform cliked")
         const option1 = {
            client_id: "432801522480-h02v02ivvti9emkd019fvreoisgj3umu.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/glogin",
            response_type: "token",
            scope: [
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            ].join(" "),
          }
          setOption(option1);
      }
 
    return (
        <>
            <button className="google-btn social-btn" onClick={() => performAuth()}>SignUp With Google</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Which `useEffect()` is called twice? The one that listens to `option`?

Comment: @PierreJanineh useEffect which listen to queryString